# How do I inject dependencies into a class instantiated by binding from appsettings in startup.cs?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration

I have a helper class that I use in startup.cs to configure certain dependencies; When I need to use it I've been grabbing an instance of it by binding some values out of appsettings.json.  Now I'd like to inject a logger into it and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.  I know I could pass in the logger in the constructor but I'm wondering if there's a way to get it to behave like my api controllers. I'm a little fuzzy on how those get instantiated.

I've tried adding the class to services before calling it; no dice. Parameterless constructor obviously works but doesn't provide dependencies.

```cs
//In startup.cs, ConfigureServices
//Pulling helper out of config and calling method
var value = Configuration.GetSection("Foo:Bar").Get<SomeClass>().SomeMethod();

//Example helper class
//SomeClass.cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<SomeClass> _logger;
    public SomeClass(ILogger<SomeClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

  //properties

    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        //do some stuff

        //log results
        return value;
    }
}
```

Either the logger dependency is null, or it complains about not having a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You should read up on Single Responsibility Principle. Looks like the helper is doing too much based on what is currently shown.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).